# Problem in finding out number of real roots of polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, roots

I am trying to find the number of real roots of the polynomial $\mathrm{f(x)=x^5-5x+3}$, using the [Sturm theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem). I have started writing out the Sturm sequence:

1. $\mathrm{p_0=x^5-5x+3}$
2. $\mathrm{p_1=5x^4-5}$
3. $\mathrm{p_2=4x-3}$
4. $\mathrm{p_3= 5-\frac{15}{4}x^3}$

However, this is where I am stuck. I have no idea how I will divide $\mathrm{p_2}$ by $\mathrm{p_3}$ to find the remainder. How do I proceed from this point?

Comment: Your $p_3$ is not (the negation of) the remainder of the division $p_1/p_2$. Since $p_2$ is of degree 1, the remainder should be of degree 0. You've only done one step of the polynomial long division.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Yes you are right. I made a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomial $p_3$ is the opposite of the remainder of the division of $p_1=5x^4-5$ by $p_2=4x-3$. Since $p_2$ has degree $1$, it follows that $p_3$ is a constant: 
 $$p_3(x)=-p_1(3/4)=-5((3/4)^4-1)>0.$$
Then the sequence of signs at $-\infty$ is $-+-+$ which has three sign changes. At $+\infty$ the sequence is $++++$ which has no sign change. Hence  the number of roots of the given polynomial $x^5-5x+3$ is $3-0=3$.